# display array data by city

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with this structure:

```
array(4) { 
     [0]=> array(x) { 
        [0]=> string(x)"London" 
        [1]=> string(xx) "John"}
     [1]=> array(x) { 
        [0]=> string(x)"London" 
        [1]=> string(xx) "Charles"}
     [2]=> array(x) { 
        [0]=> string(x)"Paris" 
        [1]=> string(xx) "Alan"}
     [3]=> array(x) { 
        [0]=> string(x)"Paris" 
        [1]=> string(x) "Wayne"} 
    }
```

How can I display the array data in this order:

**London**

John  | Charles

**Paris**

Alan  | Wayne

This can be done with an unique multidimensional array? or should i have another array to select distinct cities?

I am talking about something like a loop with:

```
foreach ($cities as $city) {
    echo '<div class="city">'.$city.'</div>';
        for() {
            echo '<div class="persons">'.$persons.'</div>';
        }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Will the cities grouped together in the original array? or is your intent to create a new array?

Comment: @mikevoermans, yes the cities are grouped in the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your cities in a new array, then spit it out

```
$newCities = array();

foreach ($cities as $city) {
    $newCities[$city[0]][] = $city[1];
}

foreach($newCities as $city => $persons) {
   echo '<div class="city">' . $city . '</div>';

   // use join to glue the pieces together
   echo '<div class="persons">' . join(' | ', $persons) . '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be convenient to create a new *associative array* as an intermediate step. This method doesn't care if the cities are originally grouped or not.

```
$cities = array();
foreach ($original_array as $entry) {
    $cities[$entry[0]][] = $entry[1];
}
```

The new array will contain city names as keys, and an array of people's names as corresponding values for each city. Like:

```
array(2) { 
    ["London"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> "John"
        [1]=> "Charles" }
    ["Paris"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> "Alan"
        [1]=> "Wayne" }
}
```

So now you can do

```
foreach ($cities as $city_name => $people) {
    echo '<div class="city">'.$city_name.'</div>';
    foreach ($people as $person) {
        echo '<div class="person">'.$person.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$array = array(
            array('0' => array('0' => 'London', '1' => 'John')),
            array('1' => array('0' => 'London', '1' => 'Charles')),
            array('2' => array('0' => 'Paris', '1' => 'Alan')),
            array('3' => array('0' => 'Paris', '1' => 'Wayne'))


       );
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $arr1) {
    foreach ($arr1 as $arr2) {
        $cities[$arr2[0]][$i] = array($arr2[0],$arr2[1]);
        $i++;
    }
}

foreach ($cities as $key => $city) {
    echo '<h2 class="city">'.$key.'</h2>';
        foreach($city as $persons) {
            echo '<div class="persons">'.$persons[1].'</div>';
        }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it may help

```
    foreach ($cities as $city) {
        echo '<div class="city">'.$city.'</div>';
            foreach ($cities as $city1) {
            if ($city==$city1){
                echo '<div class="persons">'.$persons.'</div>';
                 }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since cities are always grouped as you specified, you only need one extra variable to do this properly. Assuming your input array is called `$people`:

```
$last_city = '';
foreach ($people as $person) {
    if ($person[0] != $last_city) {
        if ($last_city != '') echo '</div>'; // Close opened persons block

        $last_city = $person[0];
        echo '<div class="city">' . $last_city . '</div>';
        echo '<div class="persons">';
    }
    else echo ' | ';

    echo $person[1];
}
echo '</div>'; // This assumes there's at least one record in $people
```

No extra associative array required. Note that this may be more semantic markup:

```
<div class="city">
    <span>London</span>
    John | Charles
</div>
```

In that case the above code would be:

```
$last_city = '';
foreach ($people as $person) {
    if ($person[0] != $last_city) {
        if ($last_city != '') echo '</div>'; // Close opened city block

        $last_city = $person[0];
        echo '<div class="city">';
        echo '<span>' . $last_city . '</span>';
    }
    else echo ' | ';

    echo $person[1];
}
echo '</div>'; // This assumes there's at least one record in $people
```